# Matrix addition of two randomly generated matrices

Tags: c, matrix

I want to do matrix addition of two 1D matrices of N elements (1xN), where the matrices generated by the code itself. I've seen many examples for this online, but in those examples user input is required, but in my case N is too large, so I want my code to generate it. So far I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n=5;
int a[5], b[5];
double sum[5];

int main() {
unsigned short i,j, k;

    for(i = 0; i < n;i++) {
      printf("%d ", a[i]=rand()%100);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n;i++) {
      printf("%d ", b[j]=rand()%100);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n;i++) {
      sum[i]=a[i]+b[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But this gives an output of 10 numbers in one line, and doesn't add them. The output is:

```
83 86 77 15 93 35 86 92 49 21 [user home]$
```

So how can I perform the addition? I'd appreciate your help as a beginner..

PS: I don't know why the output appears in front of the prompt. Also, I don't have to generate a new number since the main purpose is generating N numbers in an array.

Comment: `printf` does not automatically add a newline character to output. You need to specify it. Then, think about where in your code you're the two things required here: performing the addition, and displaying the results of the addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are doing great so far. I found some tiny miss typing in your code, like:

```
for(i = 0; i < n;i++) {
  printf("%d ", b[j]=rand()%100);
}
```

Did you mean? :

```
for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  printf("%d ", b[j]=rand()%100);
}
```

Also, you have to print the sum[] array to see the results you want.

I made some modifications to your code. Try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n=5;
int a[5], b[5];
int sum[5];

int main() {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n;i++) {
        a[i] = rand()%100;
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n;i++) {
        b[i] = rand()%100;
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n;i++) {
        sum[i]=a[i]+b[i];
        printf("%d ", sum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

ps: to break a line and avoid your string to be printed in front of your prompt, don't forget to use the "\n" escape.

edit1:

You asked about write this code in fewer lines. Well, i don't know, maybe yes. But there is something you can do: To stop repeating code.

If you are using three "for's" that do the same thing, what about use just one? Also, what about a function to print an array for you?

Try something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n=5;
int a[5], b[5];
int sum[5];

void print(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = rand()%100;
        b[i] = rand()%100;
        sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    }
    print(a, 5);
    print(b, 5);
    print(sum, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to do this task in fewer lines ?